# Hide Blank Data

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I would like to hide empty fields, not show a blank line. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a row to your details group to hold the potential list of values.  Drop a single textbox field that displays a calculated field.  The calculated field should be an expression similar to the below to display up to 4 sequential fields.

```
=Fields!ExampleField1.Value & IIF(Fields!ExampleField1.Value.ToString().Length >0,vbCrLf,"") & 
Fields!ExampleField2.Value & IIF(Fields!ExampleField2.Value.ToString().Length >0,vbCrLf,"") &
Fields!ExampleField3.Value & IIF(Fields!ExampleField3.Value.ToString().Length >0,vbCrLf,"") &
Fields!ExampleField4.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the TableRow (**not** the individual cells) you want to make conditionally suppressed, then enter the conditional suppression formula into the Visibility - Hidden property expression on the Properties tab.